# Insulate pipes in closet

Tags: plumbing, insulation

The previous homeowners ran the plumbing for the upstairs bathroom through one of the downstair bedroom closest.  They actually built wire shelving around them.  Obviously, when using the bathroom upstairs, the noise is very loud in the downstairs bedroom.

What would be the best way for me to box the pipes in and insulate them from making noise?  I'd love to board them up and build built in shelving out of wood. We live in the south, so freezing isn't really an issue.  I plan on disconnecting the outlet.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you simply boxed around it with 2x4s, insulated with fiberglass bat insulation, and covered with a double layer of drywall, it would give you quite a reduction in noise.  You will need to blank off that receptacle and leave an access panel in the front so the box is accessible.

If you frame around it with metal studs, and use homasote rather than drywall, you will achieve even greater sound insulation.

Answer (score 0):

Bats answer is perfectly acceptable.

As an alternative, if you go that route you are already going to be dealing with framing and drywall.

If you know how to plumb or are willing to pay, its not a ton of work to add a couple of inches of copper and PVC with elbows to actually get the pipes behind the wall where they belong.

In the end you aren't losing a ton of closet space framing it out, I just wanted to point out that the effort to do this *properly* wouldn't be all that much beyond what you are already getting into.  If you're making a mess with drywall do it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Noise is created in the drain pipe when air is introduced into the system.

I’ll bet if you ran a vanity or shower upstairs, there would be little/no noise in the drain pipe because the water would run down the pipe on the inside surface of the pipe. That is to say, centrifugal  force will keep the water to the outside surface of pipe.

Noise is created when you flush the toilet and the water starts tumbling.

Encasing the drain pipe and covering with insulation will help, but you’ll still hear the flushing from the toilet.

I’d replace the pipe with cast iron pipe and I’d make sure it connected to the toilet and extended down through all floors. Do not just replace the straight section of pipe.

Then add pipe insulation to water pipes so they don’t sweat in the enclosed furred space and install unfaced batt insulation around the drain pipe and then build your furring/gypsum board/etc.

BTW, that pipe looks small for a toilet to be connected into it. (Is that 3”?)